# Accessing deeply nested JSON objects in c# using NewtonSoft Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having a very difficult time reaching some deeply nested objects in my JSON

I have a directory with roughly 500 JSON files that I need to read through, and output certain data from so I load the files like this:

```
public static void getJsonFiles()
{
    int i = 0;
    string directory = @"Z:\My_JSON_FILES\DataFilesForAnalysis\DataFilesAsJSON";
    string[] jsonPath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.json");
    foreach(string item in jsonPath)
    {
        jsonReader(item, i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Once I have the file loaded, I am reading it through File.ReadAllText so I am doing this:

```
public static void jsonReader(string item, int i)
{
    string readJson = File.ReadAllText(item);
    RootObject rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(readJson);

    var resReport = rootObj.ResultsReport;
...
```

I have created objects of all of the JSON using json2csharp, but when I try to access the deeply nested objects using dot notation `(rootObj.ResultsReport.FinalReport.VariantProperties.VariantProperty.VariantName)`, I get an error 'Object does not contain a definition for FinalReport and no extension method FinalReport...'

My object definition looks like this:

```
public class VariantProperty
{
    public string geneName { get; set; }
    public string isVUS { get; set; }
    public string variantName { get; set; }
}

public class VariantProperties
{
    public string[] VariantProperty { get; set; }
}

public class FinalReport
{
    public Object Application { get; set; }
    public string ReportId { get; set; }
    public string SampleName { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Object Sample { get; set; }
    public string PertinentNegatives { get; set; }
    public Object Summaries { get; set; }
    public Object VariantProperties { get; set; }
    public Object Genes { get; set; }
    public Object Trials { get; set; }
    public Object References { get; set; }
    public Object Signatures { get; set; }
    public Object AAC { get; set; }
}

public class ResultsReport
{
    public Object FinalReport { get; set; }
    public Object VariantReport { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Object ResultsReport { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
"ResultsReport": {
"CustomerInformation": null,
"FinalReport": {
  "@xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
  "@StagingId": "XXXXXXXX",
  "@clinicalId": "XXXXXXXX",
  "Application": {
    "ApplicationSettings": {
      "ApplicationSetting": {
        "Name": "Statement",
        "Value": "XXXXXXXX"
      }
    }
  },
  "ReportId": "XXXXXXXX",
  "SampleName": "XXXXXXXX",
  "Version": "1",
  "Sample": {
    "FM_Id": "XXXXXXXX",
    "SampleId": "XXXXXXXX",
    "BlockId": "XXXXXXXX",
    "TRFNumber": "XXXXXXXX",
    "TestType": "XXXXXXXX",
    "SpecFormat": "XXXXXXXX",
    "ReceivedDate": "XXXXXXXX"
  },
  "PertinentNegatives": null,
  "Summaries": {
    "@alterationCount": "XXXXXXXX",
    "@clinicalTrialCount": "XXXXXXXX",
    "@resistiveCount": "XXXXXXXX",
    "@sensitizingCount": "XXXXXXXX"
  },
  "VariantProperties": {
    "VariantProperty": [
      {
        "@geneName": "BARD1",
        "@isVUS": "true",
        "@variantName": "P358_S364del"
      },
      {
        "@geneName": "GATA2",
        "@isVUS": "true",
        "@variantName": "P161A"
      },
      {
        "@geneName": "LRP1B",
        "@isVUS": "true",
        "@variantName": "V4109I"
      },
      {
        "@geneName": "MLL2",
        "@isVUS": "true",
        "@variantName": "P1191L"
      },
      {
        "@geneName": "NTRK1",
        "@isVUS": "true",
        "@variantName": "G18E"
      },
      {
        "@geneName": "NUP98",
        "@isVUS": "true",
        "@variantName": "A447T"
      },
      {
        "@geneName": "TET2",
        "@isVUS": "true",
        "@variantName": "D1121Y"
      },
      {
        "@geneName": "WT1",
        "@isVUS": "true",
        "@variantName": "T377_G397>S"
      }
    ]
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've followed so many different examples but it just wont seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write properties like

```
public ResultsReport ResultsReport { get; set;  }

public FinalReport FinalReport { get; set; }
```

You are using object as property type, thats wrong, it is not about JSON deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

As Volkan said the issue isn't the JSON deserialization. I got your json working by structuring my classes like so:

```
 public class VariantProperty
{
    public string geneName { get; set; }
    public string isVUS { get; set; }
    public string variantName { get; set; }
}

public class VariantProperties
{
    public List<VariantProperty> VariantProperty { get; set; }
}

public class FinalReport
{
    public Object Application { get; set; }
    public string ReportId { get; set; }
    public string SampleName { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Object Sample { get; set; }
    public string PertinentNegatives { get; set; }
    public Object Summaries { get; set; }
    public VariantProperties VariantProperties { get; set; }
    public Object Genes { get; set; }
    public Object Trials { get; set; }
    public Object References { get; set; }
    public Object Signatures { get; set; }
    public Object AAC { get; set; }
}

public class ResultsReport
{
    public FinalReport FinalReport { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ResultsReport ResultsReport { get; set; }
}
```